# parallel execution of python function

Tags: python, multithreading

My requirement is after giving control to "thread_func", while loop should continue without wait for completion of "thread_func".

Please suggest me how to approach?

```
def thread_func(mySeries):
    time.sleep(30)
    print("first value is:: ", mySeries.iloc[0])
    print("high value is:: ", mySeries.max())
    print("low value is:: ", mySeries.min())
    print("last value is:: ", mySeries.iloc[-1])
    print("=" * 20)


def testfunc():
     while True:
        data = myfunc(loop_stop_flag,1)
        mySeries = Series(data)
        my_thread = Thread(target=thread_func(mySeries))
        my_thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize thread
        my_thread.start()  # Start the execution
        stop_flag = False
```

Comment: this my_thread = Thread(target=thread_func(mySeries)) should be my_thread = Thread(target=thread_func, args=mySeries))

Answer (score 3):

The following line:

```
    my_thread = Thread(target=thread_func(mySeries))
```

evaluates `thread_func(mySeries)` before invoking the constructor of `Thread` - this is because it tries to pass the *result* of `thread_func` as `target`.

The `target` parameter should be passed a *function object*, so the correct construction would look like this:

```
    my_thread = Thread(target=thread_func, args=(mySeries,))
```

Answer (score -2):

Created a very simple class for the threading aspect. Did not duplicate mySeries, though should be simple to adapt.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class thread_func (Thread):

def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.first = 'First'

def run(self):
    sleep(5)
    print("first value is:: ", self.first)
    print("high value is:: ", self.first)
    print("low value is:: ", self.first)
    print("last value is:: ", self.first)
    print("=" * 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_thread = thread_func()
    my_thread.daemon = False  # Daemonize thread
    my_thread.start()  # Start the execution
    print('Carry on')
    sleep(3)
    my_thread2 = thread_func()
    my_thread2.daemon = False  # Daemonize thread
    my_thread2.start()  # Start the execution
    print('Three seconds in')
    sleep(3)
    print('End of main')
```